# upgrader_process_complete not sending $data array in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to run some activation code when my plugin is upgraded and hooked into the `upgrader_process_complete` action as follows:

```
add_action('upgrader_process_complete', array('Myplugin', 'plugin_updated'));

// ...
// Declared inside Myplugin class:
public static function plugin_updated($upgrader, $data)
{
    syslog(LOG_ALERT, "upgrader run with options: " . $data);
    if (is_array($data) && $data['action'] === 'update' && $data['type'] === 'plugin')
    {
        foreach($data['plugins'] as $plugin)
        {
            syslog(LOG_ALERT, $plugin);
        }
    }
}
```

The handler is called but only has the `$upgrader` passed in with no `$data`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: did you tried by setting up parameter count in hook? `add_action('upgrader_process_complete', array('Myplugin', 'plugin_updated'),10,2);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature for `add_action` is as follows:

```
add_action( $hook, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args );
```

The first two parameters are required. The third and forth are optional:

> **$priority** (int) (optional)
>
> Used to specify the order in which the
>   functions associated with a particular action are executed. Lower
>   numbers correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same
>   priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the
>   action.
>
> Default: 10
>
> **$accepted_args** (int) (optional)
>   The number of arguments the hooked function accepts. In WordPress 1.5.1+, hooked functions can take extra
>   arguments that are set when the matching do_action() or
>   apply_filters() call is run. For example, the action
>   comment_id_not_found will pass any functions that hook onto it the ID
>   of the requested comment.
>
> Default: 1

Note that the last argument, `$accepted_args`, specifies the number of parameters your function handles. If you leave this out, only 1 argument will be passed in which is what happens when `add_action` is called with only the first two arguments.

To fix this, since `plugin_updated` accepts 2 arguments, `$accepted_args` needs to be set to 2 as follows:

```
add_action('upgrader_process_complete', array('Myplugin', 'plugin_updated'),
    10 , // this is $priority which we leave at 10 because it's the default
    2 ,  // Set this to 2 since plugin_updated takes two arguments 
);
```

Thanks @Fresher for pointing this out.